# What exactly does "heda" mean?

Tags: dialogue, the-100

In the 100 TV series, we hear word "heda" or "one heda" a lot from grounders. It would make sense to mean something like leader but I've came across threads arguing that it means more than that.

So what exactly does "heda" mean?

Comment: http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Lexa

Comment: http://dedalvs.tumblr.com/post/107336833253/what-word-do-the-trigeda-use-for-commander-is

Comment: Upvote! Pay attention! dedalvs.tumblr.com blog owner is the inventor of Grounders language.

Comment: @Lettmannen - I'd post it as an answer except that a) I know nothing about this series and b) it took me four seconds to find the answer on google.

Comment: Downvoters please comment

Comment: @eYe - I didn't downvote, but I'd guess that they're following the advice offered when you mouse over the down arrow; "***This question does not show any research effort***" given that googling the title of your question leads you immediately to the answer.

Comment: @user7812 I actually got called out in StackOverflow for downvoting because the question **showed no research effort**. I don't know about here, but seems that, there, they value the site's SEO as font for information more than downvoting effortless questions.

Comment: This is very late to the game, but perhaps the term was inspired by Hedda Gabler.  This wiki permalink [describes it best](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hedda_Gabler&oldid=867783758#Critical_interpretation).

Answer (score 4):

Heda is TRIGEDASLENG for leader or commander. It is the Grounder code/slang language that was developed after the war, mainly to hide from the mountain men. Heda comes from English 'head' and the suffix 'er' (often changed in slang to 'a'). Similar to modern English slang where someone heads up a team.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out that Heda translates to leader or commander, I wanted to add that we hear this used to refer to Clark when she gets the nickname 'Wanheda' post Mount Weather incident.

Wan presumably means death and heda means commander as the nickname translates to "Commander of Death".

Answer (score -2):

heda means commander  it's the leader of all grounders even back When the collation didn't exist so basically the commander was leader over a bunch of squabbling tribes before lexa united them and became the first commander to rule over the united twelve clans hence why they call her Heda Lexa commander of the twelve clans

Comment: What does this add to the already posted answer that's almost a year old?